# Is there a way to retrieve only deleted records in last 5 minutes in Big Query Table?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Does `bigquery` support retrieving of deleted records in last 10 minutes?

Is there a way to get only deleted records?

The rows are completely removed from table and its not soft delete.

I have tried time travel feature of `bigquery` but it gives all the rows which are deleted and updated or inserted.

Comment: Do you have a primary key your rows? At least a unique identifier

Comment: Yes I do have primary key in the table @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: You need to query the table with time travel to a tempory table. Then you compare the tempory table with current table for missing rows.  But if in this 5 minutes a row was inserted and delete, you cannot find it this way. Therefore, please do not do this as a regular task. Please provide some more details: do you know which user or process is deleting rows? Can this be monitored directly?

Comment: Agree with samuel. You could also perform a self-join without temp tables. The Google Cloud engineering team is working to add the update and delete information in the change history feature: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/change-history

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that solves by using select except between the table version before deletion versus after deletion, as suggested in the comments.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  `temp.my_table` AS
SELECT
  'a' AS col_a,
  1 AS col_b,
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'b' AS col_a,
  2 AS col_b,
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'c' AS col_a,
  3 AS col_b,
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'd' AS col_a,
  4 AS col_b,
  ;
  ---
DELETE
FROM
  `temp.my_table`
WHERE
  col_a = 'a'
  OR col_b = 3;
  --- wait the required time span and set the time in the interval clause
  -- run together with the following select statement
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE before_deletion AS
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `temp.my_table` FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 8 minute);
  --
SELECT
  *
FROM
  before_deletion EXCEPT DISTINCT
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `temp.my_table` ;
```

Its worthwhile to remember that in Bigquery all the objects are immutable, so when you insert to or delete from a table, you actually creating a new table behind the scenes.

Therefore previous table states should be accessible depending on your timetravel window.